# Pasting HTML table into Excel 2007 without modifying the format of each cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, html, copy-paste

I have a table in HTML having cells storing numbers like `123.0`,`123.00`. When I use `ctrl-A` to copy the whole page into excel, `123.0` and `123.00` are all changed to `123`, which is not something I want to have.

How can I disable/stop all the pre-formatting operation in excel when I am pasting an HTML table to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can stop it from trying to fit the text into the existing formatting of the cell.  I tried using `Paste Special` which usually gives you a bit more flexibility, but even pasting it as `Text` resulted in the loss of the decimals.  With the format of the cell set as `General` it will hide them.

You can "preset" a block of cells to have the `Number` formatting (select all of them, right click, click `Format Cells...`, paste in the data and click the little clipboard icon next to the pasted range, selecting `Match Destination Formatting`.

[image]

Comment: I tried your method, it works partly, if I choose "number" in the "Format Cells...", the "123.0" is changed to "123", but if I choose "text", it will be OK. Thanks again.